# np.multiply "where" condition is problematic?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have to multiply two numpy arrays, element-wise, and, instead of using a * b, I'm interested in using np.multiply because of its "where" option, that should help me spare some computational time. In fact, I'm interested in a*b only where a third array, c, takes values > 0.

Actually, a, b and c all take values only in {0,1}, so they are "int8" arrays, and all have dimension > 3.

So I set np.multiply(a,b where=c), whit c changed to data type "bool".The function seems to work sometimes, but some other times it produces absolutely meaningless numbers in some entries, like 123 or -42 or whatever. 
Trying to figure out why, I also had this output, with some smaller arrays:

```
a,b = np.random.choice(10,size=(4,4)),np.random.choice(10,size=(4,4))

c = np.random.choice(2,size=(4,4)).astype("bool")

a

> array([[9, 6, 5, 0],
       [6, 3, 7, 9],
       [0, 4, 0, 7],
       [1, 9, 1, 9]])

b

> array([[9, 9, 2, 7],
       [8, 6, 2, 4],
       [7, 9, 6, 5],
       [8, 4, 1, 0]])


c

> array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]])


np.multiply(a,b,where=c)

> array([[81, 54, 10,  1],
       [48, 18, 14,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 1, 36,  1,  0]])
```

Where c is "False", the output is not 0 but 1.

What's wrong with this function?

EDIT: I specify that in my application of the function, a and b does not share the same shape, but the multiplication is still possible and, without the where option, returns the right result.

Comment: In other SO we've found that you need to provide the `out` along with the `where`. The current `np.multiply` docs is pretty clear about this; I don't know if that's been changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, if `where` is `False`, the corresponding locations will remain uninitialized. In your case, you can simply do:

```
a*b*c.astype(int)
```

Or if you want to use `np.multiply`, you should initialize the `out` option:

```
np.multiply(a,b,where=c, out=np.zeros_like(a))
```

Output:

```
array([[81, 54, 10,  0],
       [48, 18, 14,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 36,  1,  0]])
```

Comment: In my application, I am working with 4d arrays with a huge number of entries. In some preliminary tests I found that using "multiply(a,b where c) is faster than a*b*c. Thanks for the answer, I'm trying it out.

Comment: Well, I found that the needing of initializing a zeros array every time shortens the temporal advantage. Nonetheless, it is still relevant, around 15% for me. I still can't understand why this can't be a default setting, to set "zero" where is False.